# Parsing and changing NSPredicate

Tags: cocoa, migration, nspredicate, nsexpression

I have to migrate data from a previous app version to a new version. This also affects some predicates (`NSPredicate` instances) that were saved by users, which means that I have to change them programmatically.

Currently I try to parse the string I get with `[NSPredicate predicateFormat]` and change some  expressions manually. For instance `oldKeyPath == "something"` to `newKeyPath == "something"`. But it feels like a hack and I'm curious if there is a better way?

I read Apple's documentations about programming with NSPredicate and NSExpression. There are plenty methods to compose `NSPredicate` objects from `NSExpressions`. I was hoping to find the reverse way to get `NSExpression` objects from a `NSPredicate`. Am I missing something?

Thank you for any hint.

**Solution**

Thanks to Martin R I was able to make a category on `NSPredicate` that allows me to inject modifications to expressions.

```
@implementation NSPredicate (ExtractComparisions)

- (NSPredicate *)predicateByChangingComparisionsWithBlock:(NSPredicate *(^)(NSComparisonPredicate *))block {
  if ([self isKindOfClass: [NSCompoundPredicate class]]) {
    NSCompoundPredicate *compPred = (NSCompoundPredicate *)self;
    NSMutableArray *predicates = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSPredicate *predicate in [compPred subpredicates]) {
      NSPredicate *newPredicate = [predicate predicateByChangingComparisionsWithBlock: block];
      if (newPredicate != nil)
        [predicates addObject: newPredicate];
    }
    return [[[NSCompoundPredicate alloc] initWithType: compPred.compoundPredicateType
                                       subpredicates: predicates] autorelease];
  } if ([self isKindOfClass: [NSComparisonPredicate class]]) {
    return block((NSComparisonPredicate *)self);
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

Here is a sample code on how to use it

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"key.path like %@ and count > 17", @"Hello"];
  NSPredicate *newPredicate = [predicate predicateByChangingComparisionsWithBlock:
                               ^NSPredicate *(NSComparisonPredicate *cp) {
    NSExpression *left = [cp leftExpression];
    NSExpression *right = [cp rightExpression];
    if ([[cp leftExpression] expressionType] == NSKeyPathExpressionType) {
      NSString *keyPath = [[cp leftExpression] keyPath];
      if ([keyPath isEqualToString: @"key.path"])
        left = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath: @"key.new.path"];
      return [NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression: left
                                                rightExpression: right
                                                       modifier: cp.comparisonPredicateModifier
                                                           type: cp.predicateOperatorType
                                                        options:cp.options];
    }
    return cp;
  }];
  NSLog(@"Before: %@", predicate);
  NSLog(@"After: %@", newPredicate);
}
```

Comment: Nice! Note that you could also implement different category methods for each subclass NSCompoundPredicate and NSComparisonPredicate. That makes the isKindOfClass checks and casting obsolete (and looks sophisticated :-)

Comment: yeah I thought about that but I realized that I still have to call the method on the superclass NSPredicate since I don't know the exact kind of class or I had to cast it first. So I made the compromise and "hide" the cast in the superclass. NSPredicate doesn't look like a class that we have to extend by subclasses anyway. But I still agree for the more sophisticated way. Maybe I change it later in my code. –

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This is just an idea.) Every predicate is an instance of a subclass like
`NSCompoundPredicate` or `NSComparisonPredicate`. So you can check the actual
class of the predicate, cast it to an object of that class and then
inspect its properties. If necessary, repeat the process with sub-predicates or
expressions.

The following is just an example how a simple compound predicate could be 
"dissected" that way. It is not the general solution that checks for all cases,
but may point you into the right direction.

```
NSPredicate *p0 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"foo = 'bar' AND count > 17"];

if ([p0 isKindOfClass:[NSCompoundPredicate class]]) {
    NSCompoundPredicate *p0a = (NSCompoundPredicate *)p0;
    NSCompoundPredicateType type0 = p0a.compoundPredicateType;  // NSAndPredicateType
    NSPredicate *p1 = p0a.subpredicates[0];                     // foo = 'bar'
    NSPredicate *p2 = p0a.subpredicates[1];                     // count > 17
    if ([p1 isKindOfClass:[NSComparisonPredicate class]]) {
        NSComparisonPredicate *p1a = (NSComparisonPredicate *)p1;
        NSPredicateOperatorType type1 = p1a.predicateOperatorType;  // NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType
        NSExpression *e3 = p1a.leftExpression;                  // foo, NSKeyPathExpression
        NSExpression *e4 = p1a.rightExpression;                 // "bar", NSConstantValueExpression
    }
    if ([p2 isKindOfClass:[NSComparisonPredicate class]]) {
        NSComparisonPredicate *p2a = (NSComparisonPredicate *)p2;
        NSPredicateOperatorType type2 = p2a.predicateOperatorType;  // NSGreaterThanPredicateOperatorType
        NSExpression *e5 = p2a.leftExpression;                  // count, NSKeyPathExpression
        NSExpression *e6 = p2a.rightExpression;                 // 17, NSConstantValueExpression
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing the right direction! This is great and so simple. I will update my question to add my solution influenced by your answer.